# jQuery - Facebook style tagging with string and hidden fields regex. Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, facebook

I would like to create a similar system to the facebook status update using jQuery.

If you take a look at the guts of it, just a few elements below the `What's on your mind?` textarea tag, there is a hidden field...

```
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" class="mentionsHidden" name="xhpc_message" value="">
```

As you type a status into the textarea field, the value of this hidden field changes to match the status. However, if you tag someone into the status, the hidden field displays something like `@[uid:User Name]` in place of the users name, so that it can be turned into a hyperlink later on.

I have tried to recreate something similar myself, not with users, but with tags. http://jsfiddle.net/nickjackson/qh3QP/

When I type `#fun` into the first text area field, the second text area displays `#[tag:fun]` and the `#fun` tag becomes `fun`. This is all correct.  However, when I then type something else, the square bracket disappears because the # tag is no longer in the status field.  How can I solve this?

Ultimately, **How can I create a textarea and hidden field combo, that works similarly to the facebook status update, and allows the use of tags?**

Comment: Its happening because your re-running the replace on the main field after removing the #, i'll just have a go at your JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 3 fields - one to type in, one to store the `tag` stuff in, and one to display the text. The type-in field is invisible but on top of display field. It should be pretty self-explanatory, but ask any questions you may have - and no, I have no quick solution for there being no cursor.

http://jsfiddle.net/qh3QP/10/

Answer (score 0):

As Henry Garle stated, you are unable to have more than one encoded tag at a time  in `hidden-field`, (unless you paste text containing multiple tags in the `status-field`), because the code needs to find tags in `status-field` in order to create encoded versions of them in `hidden-field`. Since it only preserves the values of the tags in `status-field` after doing this, the next time the code runs (which is after a keypress event), it treats said values as regular text, which it simply copies in to `hidden-field`, since it is not able to identify them as values of tags.

The fix is simple: since presumably only one tag can be created at a time, all you have to do is modify your code to solely target the first appearing tag in `status-field`. Since no other tags will be targeted, their encoded versions in `hidden-field` will be preserved.

Before you of implement that fix, however, you should consider maintaining an object for each tag that contains its value and positional data instead. Such an approach separates the internal and external representations of tags, allows tags to be located quicker, and provides greater flexibility in how tags are to be ultimately formatted.

[Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator) is an existing, robust solution which takes the approach in providing the functionality you are trying to recreate. Considering it is well-structured, easy to follow, and copiously commented, it should be of use to you as either out-of-the box solution or reference material to cite as you roll out your own. It is maintained by yours truly :) .